# MAX number of Bluetooth virtual com port

Tags: bluetooth

What is the max number of BT virtual com port I can get working in my PC?
I suppose it's 7 port max, but ... using WinXP with Broadcomm (Widcomm) stack it's only one port at time. What about win7 and microsoft stack?